# My map looks different after exporting to another Baking Software

Tags: export, baking

After unwrapping and triangulating model in Blender I export it as FBX for baking. Both in Marmoset and Substance painter I got overlapping issues. Map is different, as you can see in Blender it's ok without overlapping, but after baking I see that it's full of overlaps on baked map in Marmoset. Normals are ok, it's triangulated, no double vertices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd have to ask in the respective marmoset and substance stack overflows,

Comment: best option would be to provide the file if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like the issue is both that your UV islands are way too close from each other, and your baking software uses a margin way too big.

#### Margin size

For the margin (sometimes called padding), a nice rule of thumb is to divide your model's biggest map resolution by 128.

- 256 = 2px
- 512 = 4px
- 1024 = 8px
- 2048 = 16px

See more one [Edge padding - polycount](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding)

#### UVs margins

When it comes to UVs: they have no resolution, so the margin is expressed by a factor of the total UV space. And since we want a distance of a factor of 128 and each island has its own margin, what we have to use as minimum value is `0.064`. You can go higher if you want, historically the default value was 0.16 which is a bit overboard for small resolutions but works for everything.

You can set the margin in either the Unwrap operator or Pack Islands operator options:

[image: margin setting]

#### Baking margins

In whatever baking software you use, you will have to adapt the baking margin to your model's UVs. In Blender, it's conveniently placed under Baking > Output > Margin:

[image: baking margin]

As for Substance or Marmoset, that's out of this website's scope, but they surely have either a "margin" or "padding" option somewhere.

I know Substance Painter has a "diffuse" option where it progressively fills the empty space between UVs with a gradient based on the margin. That is also a nice added bonus.